# header/footer only on the current page, or also its following pages

Tags: fancyhdr, etoolbox

I define a macro named `\pagecurrent` which will be used in other macros related to header and footer, e.g. `\cfoot, \chead, \renewcommand{\headrule}`....
It's function is to determine whether the action of the macro(`\cfoot,\chead,\renewcommand{\headrule}` etc) is only on the current page or on the rest pages also.
In the following example, I want the header content of the second page is "current page", the third page has a header "other pages".
But in fact, both pages have the same header-"current page".
I guess this is caused by "`\the\value{page}`". But I don't want to add extra code out of `\pagecurrent`.
Is there a simple approach to deal with this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,etoolbox}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%
\newcommand{\pagecurrent}[3]{%
  % #1-the current page number. If #1=0 then act on all pages from the current page, else only on the current page.
  % #2-action on the current page
  % #3-action on the following pages other than the current page
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{#1}{\value{page}}}
    or
    test {\ifnumequal{#1}{0}}
  }
  {#2} {#3}
}
% example:
first page\clearpage
\chead{\pagecurrent{\the\value{page}}{current page}{other pages}}
second page\clearpage third page
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I'd like to give the following code to make my question more clearly and concentrated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,etoolbox}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{...}\rhead{...}\cfoot{...}\renewcommand{headrule}{...}...% macros related to header/footer that defines the original header/footer content.

...some text

at a certain page: \chead{\pagecurrent{content of chead from only this page changed}} 
% all other headers/footers of this page keep there original content. All headers/footers before/after this page keep there original content.

...some text

%\chead is used to illustrate my intention, maybe other macros like \rhead, \lfoot...in real article meet also the same problem.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way but I changed your command's arguments and also added the package `atbgshi` instead of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\pagecurrent}[4][\empty]{%
% #2 is the command to be executed with:
% optional argument #1 (if not empty=default)
% argument #3 for current page and 
% argument #4 for the upcoming page.
  \xdef\FArg{#1}%
  \ifx\FArg\empty
  #2{#3}%
  \AtBeginShipout{#2{#4}}%
  \else 
  #2[\FArg]{#3}%
  \AtBeginShipout{#2[\FArg]{#4}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% example:
\section{Test section 1}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\clearpage
\subsection{Test subsection 1}
\pagecurrent{\chead}{current page}{other pages}
\pagecurrent{\cfoot}{Current Page: \arabic{page}}{Other pages: \arabic{page}}
\pagecurrent{\rhead}{Current Page:\rightmark}{\rightmark}
\pagecurrent[LE,RO]{\fancyfoot}{Current page: \thepage}{Other pages: \thepage}
second page\clearpage third page
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Test section 2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\subsection{Test subsection 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

PS: Edited to be a full example with many commands accepted

Comment: Many thanks, Koleygr. In this programme, `\chead` is put in `\pagecurrent`. My original desire is that `\pagecurrrent` can be used in all macros related to header/footer, not only in `\chead`. In my question, `\chead` is an example for the usage of `\pagecurrent`. And I need a condition(#1 in my code) to determine the header content is effective on just the current page or all pages from this page on. Is there a better way to get this?

Comment: I edited the code but I don't get the last sentence of your comment. If you want the header/footer command to be executed for the current page with an argument and then on next page to get another argument, use the updated command. If you need to execute on this page and keep its argument on the next pages, just use the original command (You could use mine too with same arguments but it would be somehow stupid.). The check of the \value{page} is not really recommended and would possibly not give you the expected result thus there are created packages like the `bophook` or the `atbegshi`.

Comment: why in `\pagecurrent{\renewcommand{\headrule}}{\rule{10em}{5pt}}{\rule{20em}{2pt}}' #4 does not work?

Comment: I don't really know how to help you... Sorry... May be you should have included a better MWE from the begining in order to find better answers than this one

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to make my questions more concentrated。That is, how to change header/footer only on the current page and meanwhile keep the original header/footer conditon in those former pages and  later pages.

Comment: @lyl Please edit your question and if you want use my answer as an example but complete it with all your expectations. You don't have to be sorry and I could delete my answer after you find a better one or after it doesn't really helps in the edited question. I don't have time this days to look in it again... So, please edit, or if this is a different question may be you can ask a new one after the new needs came out (but really has to be different). I am just adding that there is a command `\thispagestyle{<sSelectedStyle>}` that possibly could help you do what you want without hacks.

Comment: I really appreciate what you have done for me! I learnt much from your solution . I just edited my question. Would you have a look at it when it's convenient for you?

Comment: Well, your solution works perfectly when there are `\clearpage` to break pages. Yet how to achieve the same goal for those articles without page-break as iluustrated in my edited question? `\thispagestyle` alone seems not be able to deal with it.